# JavaScript based diff utility

Tags: javascript, diff

I'm looking for a *diff* equivalent written in JavaScript that only returns/prints relevant lines. I don't want both full text displayed next to each other with the differences highlighted, but just want the actual differences (plus some buffer lines to know where the difference is), similar to the output from the linux diff utility.

Does anybody know a javascript function that does this? All differences should be recognized (even changed whitespace). Thanks.

Comment: It's all good, you're too hard on yourself. By the way, great question and I wouldn't have been led to these answers without it (at least not so easily).

Comment: If @austincheney's claim below of a diff that is ~4.5 faster is genuine, and I have no reason to think it is not, I'd suggest that you consider marking his answer as accepted. That, and the even more important (imo) characteristic of highlighting character differences in each line!

Comment: John Resig's jdiff is the simplest and most effective solution out of the lot.  One javascript file required, and one line in javascript to implement: http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/#postcomment

Comment: I could be doing something wrong, but I'm actually using John Resig's thing currently and the problem with it is that it decodes whatever's different. So it looks all jacked up if tags changed, for example.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) inline mode comparison, try tweaking the context size to display just the desired window of change you want. There's a demo [here](http://cemerick.github.com/jsdifflib/demo.html)

Comment: The context size was the important thing I didn't see, thanks :)

Comment: jsdifflib is nice but it does not display the word by word diff. It just shows the lines that are different.

Comment: [jsdiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) is standard and active node.js text diff library

Answer (score 37):

I completely rebuilt the jsdifflib utility for speed.  Since my version does not require DOM access it at least 4.5 times faster, and it is also extended to highlight character differences in each line.

http://prettydiff.com/diffview.js

You can test this out with the online tool directly at http://prettydiff.com/

Comment: Can either this or jsdifflib be set to not break-up individual words?

Comment: @PeterEhrlich You should join in the Pretty Diff mailing list and provide a sample use case so that your request can be added to the project.

Comment: Just sort of doing research in to this for the moment.  Will do when I get more in to the project!

Comment: Just a follow-up: I have incorporated this baby (prettydiff) into my li'l web app and I like it. I like it a lot.

Comment: @austincheney, You did a great job, but lack of documentation make your project unable to understand. Its like hell, compared to original http://cemerick.github.io/jsdifflib/demo.html (have a look at page source)

Comment: If I check `hello` against `hel world` it misses the `rld`

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to use prettydiff in js..do I have to include only prettydiff.js ?

Comment: Documentation is pretty well hidden here: http://prettydiff.com/documentation.xhtml.  I found it by scrolling down on the demo page linked above.

Comment: OK. This thing is pretty bad - I don't know why it has so many up votes.  I can't get it to return objects of any kind.  It insists on returning HTML, which includes a mandatory tagline that's advertising for the library itself.

Comment: @RyanShillington Agreed.  It's called pretty diff too and dang it's ugly! lol

Answer (score 32):

There's also [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) from Google

Also available on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff-match-patch)

```
npm install diff-match-patch
```

Comment: This makes it more consumable, especially in a modern web browser with webpack, etc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff-match-patch

Comment: After several hours of trying different diff libraries, this one is definitely the best for comparing straight text.  It should be noted that it doesn't work really with XML/HTML.

Answer (score 8):

- [Mergely](http://mergely.com) is totally worth checking out. CodeMirror-based, client-side only.
- Then there's the [CodeMirror demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html) which requires server-side diff computation.
- [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) and [prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com/) as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: CodeMirror does not need any server-side diff computation anymore

Comment: Good to know, then they can also remove the "This addon depends on the google-diff-match-patch library to compute the diffs."-note which is still on http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html

Comment: It still needs the external JS "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff_match_patch/20121119/diff_match_patch.js", but no server side code anymore

Answer (score 6):

Checkout my minimal implementation: https://github.com/Slava/diff.js

Comment: a good, but very slow on a larger datasets

Answer (score 5):

Check out the the [wikEd diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/diff) JavaScript library. There is also an [online tool](http://cacycle.altervista.org/wikEd-diff-tool.html).

wikEd diff features inline text comparisons with block move highlighting and character/word-based resolution. It is optimized for Wikipedia source text, but works great for any type of text or code. The library code is fully customizable, has Unicode support, is extensively commented, and is in the public domain.

Answer (score 4):

I dont know much about the diff utility in linux or linux in general, but this might be what you are looking for [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib). You can find a live example there and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html). Nuff said.

Comment: *“This addon depends on the google-diff-match-patch library to compute the diffs.”*

Comment: The demo is quite impressive at first glance. I might have to check this guy out.

Answer (score 3):

old question i know, but if your doing node work or want something that is compatible with requirejs/commonjs module

I've really liked https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff

```
console.log(diff.createPatch('some file name.txt', expected, actual));
```

Comment: For future readers, this diff lib has terrible performance when diffing large amounts of text.

Comment: true, but it's excellent for small quantities of a few 100k in snapshot tests and the like

diffing large quantities in general is quite slow, written code using byte steams before to incrementally load in large files for diffing but that wasn't a off the shelf generic diffing library ! :)

Answer (score 2):

[jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) looks promising - try the demo linked from that page.