# Calculate a diff patch of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, diff, patch

I want to generate an object that will effectively be able to be applied as a patch to array A in order to produce array B.

Given a function `isSame` which compares two values and returns true if they're the same, or false otherwise (and the purpose of which is to compare two array elements), is there a known algorithm to calculate the difference between two arrays and return a list of specific differences? The differences would be composed of sets of: *X elements removed at index Y* and *the following elements inserted at index Y*.

I've written something that sort of works, but it's buggy at the moment and I'm having trouble moving forward with it, and I'm worrying that I'm reinventing the wheel when somebody else may have already done this. http://jsfiddle.net/G6tYt/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript based diff utility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053587/javascript-based-diff-utility)?

Comment: No, that's for diffing strings, I believe.

Comment: No, the algorithm is the same. It works on an array of lines.

Comment: The difference is the comparison method. I could potentially take the diff algorithm as you suggest, but swap the comparison out for my `isSame` method...?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the comparison to be both deep and tolerant of objects and arrays both, then this tool I wrote a while back might be of use:

https://github.com/danski/spahql/blob/master/src/SpahQL.DataHelper.js#L18

```
SpahQL.DataHelper.compare(
  {"a": "aval", "b": "bval", "c": "cval", "arr": [0,1,2]},
  {"a": "modified", "c": "cval", "d": "added", "arr": [0,1,2,3]}
);
// -> {"/": "~", "/a": "~", "/b": "-", "/d": "+", "/arr": "~", "/arr/3": "+"}
```